# jQuery multiple consecutive double clicks not working without moving the mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I am trying to implement background-color change (by toggling the class) on dbclick event and it only works if the mouse moves between the double clicks.

You can see the [demo](https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/) on the jQuery website has the same issue (Double click the block at the end of the page). Does anyone know how to workaround this issue or it's a jQuery bug?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with ondblclick javascript function

```js
function test() {
   console.clear();
   console.log('test');
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="test();" value="Simple click">
<input type="button" ondblclick="test();" value="Double-click">
```

Comment: when apply multiple consecutive double clicks without moving the mouse the double-click doesn't work even in the JS example you have shared. I wanted to know if anyone has figured out a way to work around this issue.

Comment: It work even if i dont move the mouse with multiple consecutive double clicks. Wich brownser are u using ?

Comment: See screen recording - not working on Chrome and Firefox. https://streamable.com/jm7uj1. I fixed the issue as er the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this:

```
 function configureClickBehavior () {
    let numClicks = 0
    $(document).on('click', 'li', function (e) {
      console.log('click this:', this)
      if (numClicks % 2) {
        //onDoubleClick()
        $(this).toggleClass('completed') 
      }
      numClicks += 1;
    })
  }
```